# How to link an .la file using Mingw

Tags: g++, mingw, dynamic-linking, portaudio, lib

I'm building portaudio under Windows 10, and I don't know how to link the `libportaudio.la` file under my `portaudio` build directory.

I used MSYS with MinGW to build portaudio, following this: http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows_mingw.html

(But I didn't `make install`)

My build command in `cmd` is:

```
g++ test.cpp -I"portaudio_dir/include" -L"portaudio_dir/lib" -lportaudio
```

and it fails with `cannot find lportaudio`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `libportaudio.la` that you assume to be the PortAudio library you
have just built is not a library.

```
$ file libportaudio.la 
libportaudio.la: libtool library file, ASCII text
```

It is a text file of key-value pairs that that `libtool` generates to facilitate platform-independent
linkage of the actual library in [GNU autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html)
projects, such PortAudio itself. You can open it in your text editor and read it.

The real (static and dynamic) PortAudio libraries that you built with:

```
./configure
make
```

are located in a hidden subdirectory:

```
portaudio/lib/.libs
```

which is usual for libraries built with autotools. It is expected that after
`make` you will run `make install` (as `root`), which will copy the libraries
and their associated header files to the default installation directories, or
the alternative ones that you specified with:

```
./configure PREFIX=<prefix_dir>
```

As you say, you didn't run `make install`. If you want to link a program against `libportaudio`
while the static and dynamic libraries remain only in the build directory, you need:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -I"portaudio_dir/include" -L"portaudio_dir/lib/.libs" -lportaudio
```

But remember that even if you successfully link a program like this against the dynamic
library `portaudio_?.dll`, that program will fail to load the DLL *at runtime*
unless the OS loader can find the DLL by its [standard DLL search algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

The easiest - but not necessarily best - way to ensure the DLL is found at runtime is to
copy it into the same directory as your program.